# About the gcc option

Tags: gcc, x86

Can I notify gcc that when compile C source file, don't use fs & gs segment registers.

Because my code use flat mode addressing, ds/es/ss/cs is enough.

Comment: on which operating system ? 32 bits or x86-64 ?

Comment: I think this issue has more relationship with gcc, not the OS.
Now I am testing with 32bit i686-gcc.

Comment: No, it has relationship with the OS, since the OS defines the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface); a compiler compiles code for a given target processor and a given ABI.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you want to avoid using `fs` & `gs` registers if your target processor and ABI define how they should be used?

Comment: I am writing a tiny os. The startup code is assembly code, after the C environment is ready it jumps to a C code entry.                     The problem is that in the assembly code I didn't use fs & gs. In the C code, I can't control that, as it is gcc's job.

Comment: You should have told that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

%GS has all sorts of uses, I think among other things it's often used for stack_guard and pointer_guard (protection canary values), Thread local storage, and possibly some special instructions.

I don't know of a switch to avoid it altogether, but maybe if you disable stack protection and avoid using TLS (or multithreading in general), you'll be able to eliminate usage of these segments in your code. Library functions linked into your executable may have it though.